# How to apply this query to all the employees

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query to compute the 3rd highest salary for an employee as shown below.

```
SELECT MAX(salary) 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  emp_no = 1 
  AND  salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) 
                 FROM   employee 
                 WHERE  emp_no = 1 
                   AND  salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(salary) 
                                       FROM   employee
                                       WHERE  emp_no = 1))
```

How can I apply this query to give the 3rd highest salary for each employee which can be fetched by the query

```
select distinct(emp_no) 
from employee
```

**Note**: without using special functions like `dense_rank()`

```
sample table 
--------------------
EMP     SALARY
--------------------
1        1000
1        1000
1        900
1        800--->Required
2        1000
2        1000
2        500
2        400---->Required
```

Comment: I would SELECT emp_no and salary, ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 3 as a sub-query, then in the outer query, select emp_no and MIN(salary).

Comment: @Tim Roberts: But what if there are duplicates in the salary column, Then what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: `DENSE_RANK` is not a "special" function. It's just one of the available analytic functions. Why would you not want to use them? That doesn't seem to make much sense to me.

Comment: You ask two different questions here.  Are there multiple records for each employee?  So, do you want "the third highest salary for employee 1" and "the third highest salary for employee 2", or are you looking for the ONE employee who has the third highest salary overall?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The table name is misleading. It should rather be called emp_salary_hist or the like. If emp_id were the primary key, then the explanation at the top of the request and the original query would not make any sense.

Comment: It was a good idea to add the data sample to your request. It is still lacking an explanation which SQL functions you consider special and which not, but I've given the request an upvote now anyway :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for each employee's third highest salary. It can happen that we find the same salary for an employee multiple times in the table, as your sample data shows. So, make the salaries per employee distinct, then rank the rows with `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` (which doesn't matter with distinct values) and then pick the third ranked.

```
select emp_no, salary
from
(
  select distinct
    emp_no,
    salary,
    dense_rank() over (partition by emp_no order by salary desc) as rnk
  from employee
) ranked
where rnk = 3
order by emp_no, salary;
```

An alternative would be to count higher salaries in a subquery and select those salaries where exist two higher salaries for the employee:

```
with distinct_salaries as 
(
  select distinct emp_no, salary from employee
)
select *
from distinct_salaries
where
( 
  select count(*)
  from distinct_salaries higher
  where higher.emp_no = distinct_salaries.emp_no
  and higher.salary > distinct_salaries.salary
) = 2;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1e17669870f2e9c7f5867bf2ee6c24bf

Comment: In my table, I have employees with salaries which have been repeated and we have to find the 3rd highest salary, without using special functions like dense_rank().

Comment: `DENSE_RANK` is no special function. It is no more special then `MAX` or `COUNT`. It is just one of the functions available in standard SQL. How do you define "special"?

Comment: Window functions have existed since standard SQL 2003. If you mean by "special" all functions that did not yet exist twenty years ago (which would be a *weird* definition) then you can count in a subquery. I've added such a solution to my answer.

Comment: Can you explain in simple words what your second query does. What is that =2 exactly doing?

Comment: The explanation is above the query. I count higher salaries and want there to be two. (For the third highest salary there exist two higher salaries naturally.) And can you explain how you define "special" functions? I still don't understand what this term is supposed to mean and why you don't want to use the straight-forward way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The instruction was to not use any function apart from the 5 aggregate functions.

Comment: Ah, okay. Back to the 1990s so to say :-) You are talking about the five aggregate functions that were defined in standard SQL 1992 (MIN, MAX, AVG, COUNT, and SUM). There exist many more aggregation functions in the current SQL standard.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from (
select e.*, dense_rank() over(order by salary desc) rnk
  FROM employee e
)t where rnk = 3
limit 1;
```

The alternative way without using dense_rank:

```
    select  e.* 
      FROM employee e
       join (
         select min(salary) as salary from(
          select distinct salary 
            from employee e 
            order by salary desc
            limit 3
           )c
        ) t on t.salary = e.salary
       limit 1;
```

Comment: Any way to do it without using `dense_rank()`.

Comment: I did not get the output from that query but is it possible to use only the 5 aggregate functions without using any special function and generate the output.

Comment: @gautam is all info of the employee needed or is just salary is mattered?

Comment: employee name and 3rd highest salary is required in a table with multiple employees.

Comment: @gautam I updated my answer, I hope this time help you :)

Comment: It says subquery in FROM must have an alias.

Answer (score 1):

This seems possible with a lateral join:

```
select e.emp_no, x.salary
from (
  select distinct emp_no
  from employee
) e
  cross join lateral (
      select salary
      from employee e2
      where e2.emp_no = e.emp_no
      order by salary desc
      offset 3
      fetch first 1 row with ties
  ) x
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6155e9e63c773a00c6aed58744a24905)

But a window function would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

> without using special functions like dense_rank()

I think you cannot do this without analytic function, because database have to analyze data between rows and order it in memory for given sub-ordered results